# Spring integration headers on message events

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration

I have a simple TCP connection factory implemented in Spring Integration:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "toTcpChannel")
public TcpSendingMessageHandler tcpOutClient() throws Exception {
    TcpSendingMessageHandler sender = new TcpSendingMessageHandler();
    sender.setConnectionFactory(clientFactory());
    sender.setClientMode(false);
    sender.afterPropertiesSet();
    return sender;
}

@Bean
public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory() {
    final TcpNioClientConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(tcpHost, tcpPort);
    factory.setSingleUse(true);
    return factory;
}

@EventListener
public void handleTcpConnectionOpenEvent(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) throws Exception {           
LOGGER.info("TCP connection OPEN event: {}", event.getConnectionId());
// HERE I would like to have "myCustomID" header here. 
}
```

I am looking for getting the custom ID that I am providing via Gateway in the produced TcpConnectionOpenEvent (or similar via interceptors)

```
@Gateway(requestChannel="toTcpChannel")
public void sendToTcp(@Payload String message, @Header("myCustomID") Long myCustomID);
```

I know this is an event not a message but I do know how to get the Connection ID that I will receive in the input channel in any other way.

I am creating a type of hash map of `my custom id – connection id`.
I cannot use a custom correlation via aggregator because the response message will not contain any information about the previously sent message. Any suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: Sorry, what is a question? The `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` is definitely about starting connection and that's true that there is no any message here to deal with. However on this event you really can store `connectionId` for your future purpose.

Comment: I need an Interceptor in the moment that I already have a connection ID and I am still have the send channel headers. My first approach is to overwrite the TcpSendingMessageHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Oh! I see. Not sure what you are going to do from your custom `TcpSendingMessageHandler`, but as far as `ApplicationEventPublisher` is single-threaded, you can store the `connectionId` in the `ThreadLocal` variable and obtain it from there after send operation.